# SQL LEFT JOIN empties out the left table columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I came across some weird behavior today with postgresql.

```
WITH actual_prices AS (
    -- Looking for prices from now to the given number of days back
    SELECT *
    FROM prices
    WHERE price_date >= now()::date - 93
)
, distinct_products_sold AS (
    SELECT distinct(id_product) as pid FROM products_sold
)
, first_prices AS (
    SELECT s.pid, p.product_id, p.price_date, p.price
    FROM   distinct_products_sold s
    LEFT   JOIN actual_prices p ON p.product_id = s.pid
)
select * from first_prices;
```

This code outputs something of this kind:

```
129 | | |
195 | | |
251 | | |
...
```

In other words, columns of table `actual_prices` are empty. I tried messing around with `JOIN` just to see what's going on: if I do `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, it empties the column of `distinct_products_sold` but the columns of `actual_prices` are displayed correctly. What can cause this?

Comment: Distinct is not a function (on a column), it's a part of SELECT DISTINCT - and works on the whole selected rows. `SELECT distinct(id_product) ...` is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT id_product ...`.

Comment: Why is it weird? There probably just aren't any matching rows in either table where `p.product_id = s.pid`.

Comment: The nature of joins is that they "empty" records out.  In the case of a `LEFT JOIN`, the records on the left side of the join will all be retained even if nothing matches, and the opposite is true for a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: @GarethD It does have an output, so there are matches. But it returns empty columns.

Comment: That would be true for an `INNER JOIN`, but the very nature of a `LEFT/RIGHT/FULL OUTER JOIN` is that there does not have to be a match in both tables for rows to be returned. [This answer on types of `JOIN`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20298671/1048425) should help you.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks a lot. Weird confusion. You can write a simple answer so I can accept something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it the wrong way around: it is not that the outer join causes data to be lost from one table, rather it forces a union between the tables by padding the missing columns with nulls e.g.

```
WITH P ( PID ) AS
(
 SELECT *
   FROM (
         VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 )
        ) AS T ( C )
),
Q ( QID ) AS
(
 SELECT *
   FROM (
         VALUES ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 )
        ) AS T ( C )
)
SELECT p.PID, q.QID
  FROM P p, Q q
 WHERE p.PID = q.QID
UNION
SELECT p.PID, NULL
  FROM P p
 WHERE p.PID NOT IN ( SELECT QID FROM Q );
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for my brainfart. Turns out it output unmatched results(how surprising). LEFT/RIGHT Joins also output unmatched results of left or right table.

P.S. Have a launch before posting a question.

Answer (score -1):

No need for `WITH` clause here , try this:

```
SELECT t.pid , p.product_id, p.price_date, p.price
FROM (SELECT distinct id_product as pid FROM products_sold) t
LEFT JOIN prices p 
 ON(t.pid = p.product_id AND p.price_date >= now()::date - 93)
```

If all the columns from table `prices` are still NULL, then there are just no matches.

A left join keeps all the records from the leading table(the left table) and only the matched data from the right table.